# Converting Check-boxes to Multiple Select Drop-down Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am newbie to rails and was working with many to many relationships. Right now I display the options as check-boxes with labels. I want to display them as check-boxes in drop-down fashion to look compact.

Here is my code:

```
    = f.collection_check_boxes :provision_ids, Provision.all, :id, :name do |b|
      = b.check_box
      = b.label
```

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32290105/rails-multiple-check-box-with-drop-down-list ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for [`select_tag`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-select_tag) with the option `multiple: true` I think. You have also some reference in this stackoverflow question: [Rails Multiple Check Box with drop down list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32290105/rails-multiple-check-box-with-drop-down-list) .

To answer your question, this should work:

```
f.select_tag :provision_ids, options_from_collection_for_select(Provision.all, :id, :name), multiple: true
```

Comment: Thanks @Pholochtairze. I implemented this but it gives me a dropdown list and no checkboxes. I want checkboxes inside dropdown for each entry for multiple selection. Hope I am clear.

Comment: @GraheshParkar I forgot to put `, multiple: true` . Now it should work.

Comment: Thanks. I combined it with jquery library chosen, working fine now.